# How to pass optional parameter to scala template in play framework 2

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Is it possible for the java controller in playframework 2 to pass optional parameter to the scala page?

I have a scala page which I'm rendering from different actions. only in a certain case one of these actions is supposed to pass a parameter to the scala, do i have to change every render call? basically i want to call template.scala.html
in 2 ways

```
template.render(msg) //java
```

and

```
template.render()//java
```

where in my template i have this:
     @(msg:String = "xyz")

currently i get an error for call with no message that it doesn't 
render(java.lang.String) in views.html.template cannot be applied to ()

Comment: Is the controller in Java or Scala?

Comment: As @TizianoPiccardi asked, it's important to know if your controller is written in Java or Scala

Comment: java, sorry for not mentioning

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/pwJYOqpupYM/r8Mfag1J-lcJ

Comment: So basically the answer is No. which sucks! now adding a so-called feature for one page requires to go and change 10s of other places the template is getting called! :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Play Framework 2 for Java the controller have to pass a default value or null. 
In other templates you can leave the optional parameter away.

Comment: i had concluded the same thing as i left it as comment, thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @nightograph - So does this basically mean that default parameters in the templating language are broken when using the Java API for play?

This seems like a bug or at least a pretty desirable enhancement. Does anyone have a reference to a request? If not I'll drop one in to start a conversation.

Comment: @alph486 haven't done much play lately, you should experiment it with new versions of it

Answer (score 9):

As a work-around you could store your parameter in the `Context.args` map. It's a `Map<String,Object>` so you can store anything that's needed for the current request.

That's an easy way of making values accessible in your templates without having to declare/pass them as parameters.

**Controller**

```
public static Result someAction()
{
  ctx().args.put("msg", "Hello world!");

  return ok(myview.render());
}
```

**template**

```
@if(ctx.args.containsKey("msg")){
  <p>@ctx.args.get("msg")</p>
}
```

Comment: This should be in the docs on their site, without any bloated examples straight to the point.